# STM32F4 SPI Tx Data Register Problem

Tags: stm32, spi

I am trying to communicate with **IS25LP128F Flash IC** via **SPI** on **STM32F407**.

> Firstly, I tried to send **RDID** command as you see in the picture.How
> to send commands and reading respond of them is explained in datasheet.

[image: readidcommand]
I use HAL library. When I checked low layer codes of "HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive or Transmit and Receive", I realized that there is a problem due to the Tx data register. The problem is when **hspi2' pTxBuffPtr** is load to **hspi->Instance->DR**, **hspi->Instance->DR** is always zero regardless **hspi2' pTxBuffPtr**' content.

> Are there anyone to had this problem before ?

Ty.

> Here is my code.

```
`void IS25LP128F_ReadID()
{
    spiData[0]=RDID;
    spiData[1]=DUMMY;
    spiData[2]=DUMMY;
    spiData[3]=DUMMY;
    StartSPI();
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2, spiData,4, 100);
    HAL_SPI_Receive(&hspi2, spiData,1, 100);
    StopSPI();
    IS25LP128F.ID=spiData[0];    
}`
```

Here is low layer code block of HAL_SPI_Transmit function.

```
 while (hspi->TxXferCount > 0U)
{
  /* Wait until TXE flag is set to send data */
  if (__HAL_SPI_GET_FLAG(hspi, SPI_FLAG_TXE))
  {
    *((__IO uint8_t *)&hspi->Instance->DR) = (*hspi->pTxBuffPtr);
    hspi->pTxBuffPtr += sizeof(uint8_t);
    hspi->TxXferCount--;
  }
```

---

> spi setup

```
` 

      hspi2.Instance = SPI2;
  hspi2.Init.Mode = SPI_MODE_MASTER;
  hspi2.Init.Direction = SPI_DIRECTION_2LINES;
  hspi2.Init.DataSize = SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPolarity = SPI_POLARITY_LOW;
  hspi2.Init.CLKPhase = SPI_PHASE_1EDGE;
  hspi2.Init.NSS = SPI_NSS_SOFT;
  hspi2.Init.BaudRatePrescaler = SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2;
  hspi2.Init.FirstBit = SPI_FIRSTBIT_MSB;
  hspi2.Init.TIMode = SPI_TIMODE_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCCalculation = SPI_CRCCALCULATION_DISABLE;
  hspi2.Init.CRCPolynomial = 10;
```

> chip select pin setup

```
 GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = IS25LP128F_CHIP_SELECT_Pin;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(IS25LP128F_CHIP_SELECT_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);
```

Comment: No, I've never had any issues using those HAL functions. Based on what you show should work, so the problem is what you don't show, like CS usage or SPI init or macro values.

Comment: @Justme startspi(); and stopspi(); are macros that calls hal gpio set and reset functions. RDID = 0xAB, Dummys are equal to zero.

Comment: Writing to the DR is a one-way operation. You can't read DR to see what you've written. Reading DR gives you data which the SPI peripheral has received (if any).

Comment: What result do you get in your `spiData[0]` after the Transmit & Receive complete? Do the Transmit & Receive calls both return `HAL_OK`? What does your SPI & GPIO init code look like?

Comment: @brhans sometimes program falls timeout due to the RXNE flag not set, sometimes DR returns FF, i saw couple of times what I expect to see.. I shared spi and gpio setup.

Comment: Do you have enabled SPI clocks?

Comment: Clocks are enabled in functions. @Misaz

Comment: Are you stepping through the code with a debugger? Have you tried just letting it run? If your debugger is reading the DR while you're stepping, that will clear the RXNE flag just the same as if it was code reading DR.

Comment: @brhans Yes. I let it run and there is no problem. Lmao. Does SPI's high frequency effect debugging ?

Comment: @brhans When I clicked "Resume", codes runs and Data are crushed. Whenever I paused and started step over functions in main routine, data comes properly. I do not know why this is happening.

Comment: @brhans a little bit delay fixed this.